# Python socket dictionary with select

Tags: python, sockets, dictionary

For some reason I cannot match select sockets to my dictionary of sockets. The below code creates a dictionary of sockets (which is does) then when someone connects accept (which it doesn't). It finds 's' in 'L', but then cannot `socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

```
listening = {}
L = []
for link in links:
    try:
        # listening
        listening[link] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listening[link].bind((host, routers[routername].baseport+links[link].locallink))
        listening[link].listen(backlog)
        # append routes and listen-list
        L.append(listening[link])
    except socket.error, (value,message):
        print "Could not open socket: " + message
        sys.exit(1)

# run loop
input = L
running = 1
while running:
    inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[], 0)

    # Sockets loop
    for s in inputready:
        if s in L:
            # handle the server socket
            client, address = s.accept()
            input.append(client)
```

Comment: Your introductory paragraph there confuses me... can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I'd love to, which part specifically or do you mean the whole thing?

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing the second and third sentences.

Comment: `s` is the iterator in the for loop which handles all ready sockets from the select statement, and I'm lost trying to describe the error. As for the previous statement, I was just trying to describe my predicament. I have since solved my dilema and will post a simplified solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although unsure of all my wrongs in the first attempt, I have since solved my own dilema. @Jeremy was on the right track, but slightly off (probably due to my description). The sockets don't get referenced outside of `s` and therefore do not need to be a dictionary. However, select only takes a list so rather than complicating things with other data types, stick with a list and reference `s` instead of `L` (`s` is what you want anyways)

```
L = []
input = [sys.stdin]

for i in range(4):
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    server.bind((host,port+i)) 
    server.listen(backlog)
    L.append(server)
    input.append(server)

running = 1
print len(L)
while running: 
    inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[]) 

    for s in inputready: 
        if s in L: 
            # handle the server socket
            print "opened"
            client, address = s.accept() 
            input.append(client)
        elif s == sys.stdin: 
            # handle standard input 
            junk = sys.stdin.readline() 
            running = 0 
        else: 
            # handle all other sockets 
            data = s.recv(size)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you add the append client socket to (input), you are also adding it to (L).  This happens because input and L are both pointing to the same list object.  Then, when the newly-connected-client-socket sends you some data, you try to call accept() on the client socket, but of course the client socket is not a listening socket, so you get the error you saw.

As an example of why input.append(client) adds client to L, here's a snippet from my Python interpreter:

```
Jeremys-Mac-mini:python lcsuser1$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> print L
[1, 2, 3]
>>> input = L
>>> print input
[1, 2, 3]
>>> input.append(4)
>>> print input
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print L
[1, 2, 3, 4]  <-- d'oh!
```

For a fix, replace the line

```
input = L
```

with

```
input = list(L)
```

So that input points to a copy of L, rather than pointing at L itself.